# Azure container is inaccessible through browser

Tags: azure, storage

When I hit the URL I get this: -

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<EnumerationResults ServiceEndpoint="https://bmiplstorageacc.blob.core.windows.net/" ContainerName="bmiplcontainer">
<Blobs>
<Blob>
<Name>APTITUDE & REASONING TOPICS.PNG</Name>
<Properties>
<Creation-Time>Wed, 16 Nov 2022 12:39:56 GMT</Creation-Time>
<Last-Modified>Wed, 16 Nov 2022 12:39:56 GMT</Last-Modified>
<Etag>0x8DAC7CFAAA27D93</Etag>
<ResourceType>file</ResourceType>
<Content-Length>40678</Content-Length>
<Content-Type>image/png</Content-Type>
<Content-Encoding/>
<Content-Language/>
<Content-CRC64/>
<Content-MD5>IKfsZIstgzA+I0WBgJ+2aw==</Content-MD5>
<Cache-Control/>
<Content-Disposition/>
<BlobType>BlockBlob</BlobType>
<AccessTier>Hot</AccessTier>
<AccessTierInferred>true</AccessTierInferred>
<LeaseStatus>unlocked</LeaseStatus>
<LeaseState>available</LeaseState>
<ServerEncrypted>true</ServerEncrypted>
</Properties>
<OrMetadata/>
</Blob>
</Blobs>
<NextMarker/>

</EnumerationResults>
```

I can access blobs directly but unable to access the container.

Comment: What do you expect to see?

Comment: I expect to see the folders and want to access them, as you can see in above code I had an image stored in there but instead of image it is showing <Blobs>
<Blob>
<Name>APTITUDE & REASONING TOPICS.PNG</Name>
<Properties>

Comment: Simple answer is you cannot. Basically you are invoking [`List Blobs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs?tabs=azure-ad) REST API operation when you type the container URL in browser's address bar.

Comment: So is there any way by which I can access the azure containers on browser.

Comment: You would need to write some code (HTML/JS) to parse the XML and present it in the browser.

Comment: where do I need to put that code, in URL ?

Comment: And can we access images and videos through browser after parsing?